# Trying to Find Duplicate Records in Access Error

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am making a databse for a sports club, 
When filling out a form, they input the facility ID, start time, end-time and date.
What I am trying to do is when they enter the end time box, the function scans through the entries on the 'Bookings' Table where all the data from this form is stored, to see if the facility is booked out at this time. ( For dtermining if it is booked out at a certain time, if the start time or the end time on table is between what is filled in on the form, an error is thrown
The code is shown below:

```
Private Sub EndNon_AfterUpdate()
    Dim criteria As String
   criteria = _
      "Non-PlayingFacilityID= " & Me.NonPlayID.Value & " " & _
      "Date(Non-PlayingFacility)= " & Me.DateNon.Value & _
      " " & "AND [StartTime(Non-PlayingFacility)] Between Me.StartNon.Value And Me.EndNon.Value OR [EndTime(Non-PlayingFacility)] Between Me.StartNon.Value And Me.EndNon.Value "

   If DCount("*", "Bookings", criteria) > 0 Then
      MsgBox "Unfortunately, this facility is booked at this time"
      Me.Undo
   End If

End Sub
```

Syntax error is thrown when I run this, not sure why.
Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

It probably highlights this invalid syntax:

```
"Date(Non-PlayingFacility)= " & Me.DateNon.Value & _
```

Perhaps you mean:

```
"DateValue([Non-PlayingFacility])= " & Format(Me!DateNon.Value, "\#yyyy\/mm\/dd\#") & _
```

The remaining date comparisons need to be concatenated and formatted similarly.

Addendum - given the obscure field name:

```
"[Date(Non-PlayingFacility)]= " & Format(Me!DateNon.Value, "\#yyyy\/mm\/dd\#") & _
```

The format is needed to create a valid string expression in SQL for the date value. This is independent of a format applied for display.

Comment: Gustav, The variable name is actually "Date(Non-PlayingFacilty)". I understand this is misleading tldue to the brackets and will change it. An input mask is used for the Date on Value in the form so the format is correct so no need to change it, thanks

Comment: No. You will have to adjust the full code - as noted in my answer.